# How to stop carousel responding to mobile device?

Tags: bootstrap-5, owl-carousel

This carousel puts text below the image only when on a 'mobile' device but I want it to be below the image on all devices/screen sizes. I just can't figure out what I need to change to get this to work - is it the styles_test.css somewhere?

```
<section class="ftco-section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="heading-section mb-5">owl carousel</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="md-12">
                <div class="sidetext-carousel owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item" data-hash="one">
                    <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
                    <div class="img order-md-last" style="background-image: url(01.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="text text-center text-lg-center p-4 px-xl-5 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="desc w-100">
                        <p class="h5">Slide One</p>
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <p>1 text - Need to always have this text below image</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="two">
                    <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
                    <div class="img order-md-last" style="background-image: url(02.jpg)"></div>
                    <div class="text text-center text-lg-center p-4 px-xl-5 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="desc w-100">
                        <p class="h5">Slide Two</p>
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <p>2 text - Need to always have this text below image</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Try this code now tested:

```
<section class="ftco-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="heading-section mb-5">owl carousel</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="sidetext-carousel owl-carousel">
          <div class="item" data-hash="one">
            <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 order-md-last">
                  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(01.jpg); height: 500px; background-size: contain; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-left align-self-center">
                  <div class="desc" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p class="h5">Slide One</p>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <p>1 text - Need to always have this text below image</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-hash="two">
            <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 order-md-last">
                  <div class="img" style="background-image: url(01.jpg); height: 500px; background-size: contain; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-left align-self-center">
                  <div class="desc" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p class="h5">Slide Two</p>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <p>2 text - Need to always have this text below image</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: edit: fixed it even more now

Comment: Thanks - I got it working by changing all the 'md' and 'xl' references in your code to 'xs'